# Why does this code produce 1 on adding characters in C?

Tags: c

I was trying to restrict user input from alphabets (Eg: repeat input until correct input is provided ) , in order to get only numbers to be added. Somehow, instead of able to do so, I was able to add alphabets, but with out being '1'

It increments 1 if a number with a character is given.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x,y;
    while(1)
    {
         printf("Enter a number > ");
         if(scanf("%d%d",&x,&y) != 1){
             printf("%d",x+y);
             break;
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the reason behind it?

Comment: Sorry...what? Can you make it more clear?

Comment: What input are you using exactly, what output are you getting, and what output did you expect?

Comment: restrict user input? dont use scanf then. use fgets/sscanf

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am using number as inputs, and trying to restrict the input to numbers. Basically trying to repeat the input process until i get 2 numbers. In case i give a character as input, the result is incremented by one (example input: a b) output : 1

Comment: @interjay i used inputs : a b, i expected me to ask again for input, but the output produced was 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions it has performed for the input given.

With

> ```
> scanf("%d%d", &x, &y)
> ```

you ask for two integers so `scanf()` will return `2` if it was successful. Your code however checks for `!= 1` which will also be true if `scanf()` returns `0` becuause you entered "a b" and no conversation could be performed.

If not all conversions were successful, all characters not being part of a successful conversion remain in `stdin` and the next `scanf()` will try to interpret them again and fail. To prevent that from happening you have to "clear" them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
         printf("Enter two numbers: ");
         int x, y;  // define variables as close to where they're used as possible
         if (scanf("%d%d", &x, &y) == 2) {
             printf("%d\n", x + y);
             break;
         }
         else {
             int ch;  // discard all characters until EOF or a newline:
             while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The more ideomatic way:

```
int x, y;
while (printf("Enter two numbers: "),
       scanf("%d%d", &x, &y) != 2)
{
    fputs("Input error :(\n\n", stderr);
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

printf("%d\n", x + y);
```

Comment: The problem may be elsewhere....for a non-numeric input it'll keep failing as the input is not consumed, and would likely cause problem.

Comment: thanks for that one, but I'd like to learn more about the output produced, example: a+b results in 1 and 12+a results in 13

Comment: If you enter `a b` your code will execute `printf("%d\n", x + y);` using garbage values for `x` and `y` since they were never written to and contain indeterminate values. For `12 a` the condition of your `if` won't be true and the next `scanf()` will also fail returnin `0` your condition getting true and `printf("%d\n", x + y);` printing garbage.

Comment: @Swordfish 1) I never said the code was correct, it was referring to the then state of your answer, 2)the comment was made just before your expansion. :)